# cumsum reset based on new customer number

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataset that looks like this. 
[image]

What I am trying to do is the following

- For each customer number, sum credit amount, sum debit amounts(oldest to   newest) until debit cumsum = credit amount *-1
- Credits can apply to partial invoices
- Return a list of document numbers (and amounts) to apply credits to for each customer

`df['debcum_sum'] = df.groupby(['CustNum'])['Debits'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())`

I was going to add a column for the cumsum but I would like to try and to this as a for loop.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why on earth use a loop when you can just: `df.groupby(['CustNum'])['Debits'].cumsum()`?

Comment: Then what would my next step be in order to have the debit cumsum stop when it is equal to the credit cumsum for the same customer?

Comment: Ah, stating your actual problem was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible data set (in text/CSV/Python code form) and your desired data set?

Comment: MaxU- how to I attached a CSV to a question?

Comment: @HannahSawyer Many ways you can share a `csv` - if the `csv` file is considerably "small" in size you can copy & paste the csv text contents directly into the question here, or share a link to it on a resource-sharing site like [sharecsv.com](http://www.sharecsv.com/), [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/), or something like [www.pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `groupby` + `cumsum`, and then `pd.Series.where`/`mask` to hide values based on the `Credit` column -

```
v = df.groupby(['CustNum'])['Debits'].cumsum()
df['debit_cumsum'] = v.where(v >= df['Credit'] * -1)
```